# get-content issue

Tags: powershell

Basic powershell question here - I have two computers in the c:\temp\servers.txt file and want to query the tcpip.sys file version info. I keep on getting an error but it also seems to work....

> PS C:\Windows\System32\drivers> Get-Content C:\temp\servers.txt |
>   ForEach-Object (Get-ChildItem c:\windows\system32\drivers\tcpip.sys).Versioninfo

I get the below error:

> ForEach-Object :> Cannot bind parameter 'Process'. Cannot convert the "File:
>   C:\windows\system32\drivers\tcpip.sys InternalName:     tcpip.sys
>   OriginalFilename: tcpip.sys.mui FileVersion:      6.1.7600.16385
>   (win7_rtm.090713-1255) FileDescription:  TCP/IP Driver Product:
>   Microsoftr Windowsr Operating System ProductVersion:   6.1.7600.16385
>   Debug:            False Patched:          False PreRelease:
>   False PrivateBuild:     False SpecialBuild:     False Language:
>   English (United States) " value of type
>   "System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo" to type
>   "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock". At line:1 char:49
>   + Get-Content C:\temp\servers.txt | ForEach-Object <<<< 
>   (Get-ChildItem c:\windows\system32\drivers\tcpip.sys).Versioninfo
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ForEach-Object],
>   ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to construct a UNC path to each each server:

```
Get-Content C:\temp\servers.txt | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-ChildItem \\$_\c$\windows\system32\drivers\tcpip.sys).Versioninfo 
}
```

You also need to use braces, not parenthesis, that's why you the error.

Comment: Thanks for that. When I execute the code I get "File Version" as 6.1.7600.138..... => can you please advise how I can see the entire number? I tried fromat-table - not too sure how I can space the results - thanks.

Comment: Which property you want to display? Have you tried to pipe to format-list? Also try: ...Versioninfo.FileVersion

Comment: Figured it out - I used Format-table -Autosize. Thanks a lot.